# Converting from string to int for implementation into Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am working on a web form that takes the input of information and stores it to a dictionary, then adds it to a listbox.

**newAccount.ID** is set as an integer inside the Account class. And I have parsed it in the click event. However, it says "Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'int' to 'string'. I am currently checking to see if the dictionary contains the account ID before adding an exception.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Account newAccount = new Account();

        newAccount.ID = int.Parse(txtID.Text);
        newAccount.Balance = double.Parse(txtBalance.Text);
        newAccount.Name = txtName.Text;

        if (myAccounts.ContainsKey(newAccount.ID))

    }
```

Comment: never use `double` for money, use `decimal`

Comment: May you try : newAccount.ID.ToString() ?

Comment: @Youssef13, That sort of fixed it. I totally forgot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your `dictionary` key is `string` not `integer`. First of all that is not the best, as the data you want to keep there is of type `int`

If you want to keep that though:

```
newAccount.ID.ToString();
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: Well for the dictionary, I am attempting to use it to store all the accounts. But your suggestion solved it. I tried everything except ToString. Thank you!

Comment: probably dictionary is wrong declared to such algorithm.